# Matlab: Run code while preventing user intervention

Tags: matlab, security, organization, release-management

I have a business-critical process implemented in Matlab. It is basically a script that will be called once per day, and results will be used to make business-critical decisions. I need to make sure that the results that are generated by the script are reliable in a business-sense, i.e. it needs to be revision-proof. We have a proper release process, so a release manager is the only one with write-rights to the production code environment.

Since Matlab is an interpreted language, a user could at any point of the execution of the approved code just press Ctrl+C to cancel execution, modify data, and coninue execution. For my results' paper trail I need to prevent that from happening.

The programs purpose is to generate financial and economic indicators from various data sources, which are saved and used to assist decision making investment decisions in a financial institution. Thus, the users are the developers, and any kind of modification as described above can be assumed to be non-malicious. The results just must be revision proof. We are a team of three researchers / fund managers, and by regulation are required to have some process in place, but no specifics, and obviously we would primarily get work done.

My current idea is as follows: Have a change manager role whos task it will be to test and approve newly developed code to the production environment. The production environment is neither readable nor writable and contains all relevant matlab scripts and code, as well as config files. A neither readable nor writable, but executable script will start the Matlab interpreter and our main program with another user with elevated access to the production directory. Results will be saved (using the elevated rights of that specific user) in a kind of 'append only' folder. Then the program will exit.

Is this an acceptable way of implementing things? What would be things to consider that I forgot? Alternative approaches?

Thank you!

Comment: So you want to [protect your source code?](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/protect-your-source-code.html)

Comment: If you have something to hide then send the compiled version. Don't annoy people by making it look like an editable .m file

Comment: If you have no control over the machine the code is running on, you have no control over the integrity of the results. "Since Matlab is an interpreted language" – a (sufficiently competent) user can interrupt code execution of any program at any time with a debugger and modify data. You can only make it harder by supplying a compiled or obfuscated version.

Comment: There is no interupt handler for compiled mex functions, so I'd suggest writing a mex function that calls your script through the matlab c/c++ interface. I have never tried this specific scenario, but I know that I cannot interrupt my mex files (though they do not call matlab native functions from within them) with ctrl-c from the matlab command prompt.